# Check for existing jobs in queue

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, php, queue

Is it possible in code to search for a job/list out all jobs?

I have built a plugin that scans an external API and I want to scan on an interval as well as allow the user to fire off a manual scan. I have found on quicker intervals that the queue can get overwhelmed with jobs quicker than it is able to complete them eventually taking the site down as a whole.

Is there any way to query the queue list for current jobs? either search by name or just get the full list so I can loop through them?

also is it possible to release specific jobs or all jobs from code?

Thanks for any help given

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the queue component using `\Craft::$app->getQueue()`. Keep in mind that this *may* return null or a non-compatible component depending on configuration, so make sure to check if the queue component is an instance of the `craft\queue\QueueInterface`.

The default queue component ([craft\queue\Queue](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-queue.html)) has all the methods you need to build your interface:

- [Queue::getJobInfo()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-queue.html#method-getjobinfo) returns an array with information on all active queue jobs (up to the specified `$limit`).
- [Queue::release()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-queue.html#method-release) to release a specific job or [Queue::releaseAll()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-queue.html#method-releaseall) to release all jobs.
- [Queue::retry()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-queue.html#method-retry) to retry a specific job or [Queue::retryAll()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-queue.html#method-retryall) to retry all.
- … and so on.

A good place to discover how Craft uses these core features are the CMS controllers. In this case, [craft\controllers\QueueController](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-controllers-queuecontroller.html) contains all the endpoints / actions used by the Queue Manager utility and will show you how Craft uses the service methods to build the interface.

> I have found on quicker intervals that the queue can get overwhelmed with jobs quicker than it is able to complete them eventually taking the site down as a whole.

This is a bit troubling because the queue should never be able to take down the site. Make sure you're service supervisor gives the queue runner a low priority so it doesn't interfere with site requests. See the article [Robost queue job handling in Craft](https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms#solution-2-forge-daemons) for more information.